# What is the proper way to specify that a JAR is provided by the application container so it should not be included in an EAR or WAR file?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a JAR that depends on another JAR that is provided by the application container (so it is not included in the WAR file). But it needs to be included in the package when that component is used in a different standalone application.
What is the proper way to specify that a JAR is provided by the application container so it should not be included in an EAR or WAR file, but included when packaged in a standalone application?

Here is the dependency tree:

```
WAR(app1) JAR(app2)
 +        +
 |        |
 v        v
 Dependency
   +
   |
   v
Dependency (provided by the application server)
```

This is the pom.xml of the JAR that depends on a JAR provided by the application container, but required if building a standalone application.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduledao</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml of the web application:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduledao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml of the standalone application:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>standaloneapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduledao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What is a "standalone application"? Are you saying your jar is a library included in other projects?

Comment: Use `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: @chrylis a "standalone application" is not run inside an application server, but just with java -jar application.jar

Comment: @PawełGłowacz If I use `<scope>provided</scope>`  that dependency will not be included in the package of the standalone application

Answer (score 3):

As others said, you need to set the scope.

**BUT**

In order to use it in 2 different cases, you need to declare 2 profiles, the application container based one and the standalone application one which will have a propery named e.g. `profile.scope`. 
In first case it will be `provided` and `compile` in second and you must use each profile respectively depending on the case you need to run.

sth like this

```
<profile>
    <id>appServer</id>
        <profile.scope>provided</profile.scope>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>standaloneApp</id>
        <profile.scope>compile</profile.scope>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

and then

```
<scope>${profile.scope}</scope>
```

Comment: I do not understand why you suggest using profiles if there is only one way to build the WAR and the JAR. You seem to understand that the WAR and the JAR are the same application. But they are different applications.

Comment: what do you mean by standalone application? be more specific please.

Comment: post your `pom.xml` file

Comment: @JohnSmith so you have 2 different pom's for these 2 apps?

Comment: I have posted the pom.xml files of the module (that depends on the module that is provided by the application server), the web application WAR, and the standalone application. Yes, I have 2 different pom.xml files for the 2 different applications

Comment: so in your first pom why dont you put a property as a scope tag and set it to provided or compile depending on the situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need three projects:

1. "core": Application Core with all the logic with default packaging
2. "web": Web Application with `war` packaging
3. "standalone": Standalone Application with default packaging

In core `pom.xml` you define all dependencies as they are required for your application logic, with default scope.

In web `pom.xml` you define dependency on core with default scope, and additionally you define all dependencies that are provided by container with `<scope>provided</scope>`. These additional dependencies will basically override dependencies in core and will end up not being bundled in `.war`. If you have any tests, they will run with the `provided` dependencies - this can be important if the versions are different and you want to make sure your app works with the versions that will be on the application server. This project might also contain some additional code for running within application container.

In standalone `pom.xml` you define dependency on core, and additionally any dependencies necessary for it to run standalone, such as command-line parsing library, etc. Additionally you'll define here settings for running this as standalone application, such as `maven-jar-plugin` to include main class in manifest. This project might also contain some additional code for running standalone.

Comment: If there is almost nothing to be put in standalone `pom.xml` and almost no additional code for running standalone (just some single basic main class), you might be tempted to merge this project with core. You can, but I would suggest keeping them separate anyway to ensure everything is clean. After all, having and extra Maven project doesn't really cost you anything.